# Getting values in a pandas df below the diagonal

Tags: python, pandas

I have a matrix dataframe and I would like to get just the values on the second half on the diagonal (so everything under the 1 in the example below). I would like the result to be a new dataframe with one column with all of these values listed, but I'm not sure exactly how to go about this.

Shortened version of my df:

```
Word    toxin    sloppy  grief
toxin   1       -0.03    -0.06
sloppy  -0.03    1       0.09
grief   -0.06    0.09    1
```

Ideal df:

```
Column
-0.03
-0.06
0.09
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`np.tril_indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tril_indices.html) to obtain the indices of the lower-triangular elements. Then use NumPy indexing (e.g. `values[np.tril_indices(...)]`) to obtain those values in an array:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Word': ['toxin', 'sloppy', 'grief'],
 'grief': [-0.059999999999999998, 0.089999999999999997, 1.0],
 'sloppy': [-0.029999999999999999, 1.0, 0.089999999999999997],
 'toxin': [1.0, -0.029999999999999999, -0.059999999999999998]})


values = df[df['Word']].values
lower_triangular = values[np.tril_indices(values.shape[0], -1)]
print(pd.DataFrame({'Column': lower_triangular})
```

yields

```
   Column
0   -0.03
1   -0.06
2    0.09
```

Answer (score 1):

***`numpy.tril_indices`***
similar to @unutbu's answer but preserving the indices with a multi-index

```
v = df.values
i, j = np.tril_indices_from(v, -1)
pd.Series(v[i, j], [df.index[i], df.columns[j]])

Word          
sloppy  toxin    -0.03
grief   toxin    -0.06
        sloppy    0.09
dtype: float64
```

***`numpy` broadcasting + `pandas` `mask` + `stack`***

```
rng = np.arange(len(df))
df.mask(rng[:, None] <= rng).stack()

Word          
sloppy  toxin    -0.03
grief   toxin    -0.06
        sloppy    0.09
dtype: float64
```